# Toasts in Android

Tags: android

One of the parameters for `Toast.makeText()` method is the context.

And for that parameter, I can see value is given as `ActivityName.this` in some Android textbooks.

Shouldn't this be `this.xxx`?

Comment: How did you compare `ActivityName.this` and `this.xxx`? `this.xxx` will always refer member of class not itself.

Comment: u are saying `this` or `this.xxx`

Answer (score 1):

Not always, it depends where you are creating the Toast. If, for example, you creating the toast in the `onClick` method of a `Button` click listener, `this` would be the Button, which cannot provide a context.

Comment: you can not use `this` in click listener only if it is anonymous class..there is several way of implementing listener ..One way is to declare the  `android:onClick="click"` attribute to button XML and declare the method `click(View v){//perform the task}`..In this case listener is not a anonymous class

Comment: It was just a possible example to explain why you cannot always use this as context. I was not going to do a lecture about this.

Comment: Take it easy .u just mentioned click listener therefore I pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

`ActivityName.this` gets the reference to the object of the enclosing class with that name, if the code is in an nested class. For example, if you write this code inside your `Activity`'s code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    // ...
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // An anonymous nested class
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Example", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            // This one causes an error; this is not a Context
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Example", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            // This one works
        }
    });
}
```

The first `this` now refers to a object of the type `OnClickListener`. It is not a `Context`, so it's an error. The second one refers to the local `YourActivity`, which is an `Activity` and so a `Context`, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you are inside an inner class of `ActivityName`, you call `ActivityName.this`. If you are not in an inner class, you just call `this`.
The point is to refer to the `Activity` and use it as a context.